# Display Dashboard Chart using Existing Sales Records available in Database, in Customised Django admin Panel

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, plotly

I have created customised Admin Panel using Python & Django.

Now in my case there are several Tables in Database. But more importantly I want to show charts of Past 6 months sales in Django admin Panel.

I have tried to Create a Chart using Plotly. By using Static Data its already done & works.

**Here is what I have tried :**

```
from plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter

def index(request):
    x_data = [0,1,2,3]
    y_data = [x**2 for x in x_data]
    plot_div = plot([Scatter(x=x_data, y=y_data,
                        mode='lines', name='test',
                        opacity=0.8, marker_color='green')],
               output_type='div')
    return render(request,'index.html',{'plot_div':plot_div})
```

But don't exactly know how to connect with Actual data available in Database in Order section.
Can some one guide me how to do this ?

**Important Note :**

- I have checked several examples but most of them using static data only which comes through JS files.
- I have already implemented using the Static data adding to the .py file. But now the same thing I need to implement using the Database.

Any suggestions or references will be highly appreciated.